# How can I prevent mUI from showing dropdown menu after Chrome autofills a user's address?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, autofill

I'm creating a form for a user to input their address for the purposes of collecting a billing address for payment information. We only serve customers within the United States so there is an autocomplete mUI component with a dropdown menu so that the user can select which state they live in. Here is the code we are using for that:

```
export const stateNamesAndAbbreviations: ReadonlyArray<StateNameAbbreviation> = [
  { name: "Alabama", abbreviation: "AL" },
  { name: "Alaska", abbreviation: "AK" },
  { name: "Arizona", abbreviation: "AZ" },
  // Shortened for brevity. . .
]

const StateDropdown: React.FC<StateDropDownProps> = ({state, fieldUpdated}) =>
    <Stack width={"100%"}>
        <InputLabel shrink>State</InputLabel>
        <Autocomplete size="small" 
            autoSelect
            autoHighlight
            selectOnFocus
            options={stateNamesAndAbbreviations.map((x) => x.abbreviation)}      
            data-testid={NewPaymentMethodTestHandles.State}
            onChange={(event, newValue) => fieldUpdated(PaymentMethodFields.state, newValue!)}
            renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField variant="outlined"
                    {...params}
                    error={state.isDirty && !state.isValid}
                    helperText={state.isDirty && !state.isValid ? "State is required" : null}
                    data-testid={NewPaymentMethodTestHandles.StateInput}
                    onChange={(event) => fieldUpdated(PaymentMethodFields.state, event.currentTarget.value)}
                    onBlur={() => !state.isDirty && fieldUpdated(PaymentMethodFields.state, state.value)}
                    inputProps={{
                        ...params.inputProps,
                        autoComplete: "address-level1",
                    }}
                />
            )}
        />
    </Stack>
```

Edit: **A code sandbox is available [here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-roman-lmn97l?file=/src/App.js)** It's stripped down but has the same problem: if you select the "Name" box and autofill an address saved in your browser the state dropdown menu opens rather than being auto filled.

The dropdown works fine in tandem with the rest of the form which we use to collect first name, last name etc. The issue is when it comes to the browser autofilling a saved address. All of the fields will be populated properly *except* the state dropdown component, which for whatever reason simply opens the dropdown menu instead of being populated with the state name. I'm still able to properly submit the form by manually selecting a state, and even have the browser save the address I inputted, but autofill does not seem to work on this field. I verified the state is indeed attempting to go to the correct field, since if I remove the dropdown functionality but keep the textfield intact the state gets autofilled correctly. Additionally, when Chrome brings up the menu to autofill the information hovering on it to to preview the info it is about to autofill, the state will be previewed in the correct place.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: could you provide a codesandbox.io perhaps?

Comment: @Damzaky Code sandbox is now live, as I say in the question it is a bit stripped down but it still has the same issue. My apologies for the delay in getting it up

Comment: I'm curious why `.abbreviations` and not `.name`

Comment: in my answer i use `.name` instead of `.abbreviations` because in Japan do not use area code like that

Comment: @TachibanaShin The full version of this form uses the stateNamesAndAbbreviations to convert between a states name and abbreviation for API calls and such, it's largely irrelevant to this single part of the form. All it's being used for here is to generate an array of state abbreviations to function as a list of options that the user can choose from. We're only serving US clients so we don't account for international addresses in the form.

Comment: @Shades it is quite involved in my solution i need to check if input will actually be initials or full name and check if it is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i'm not an expert in react nor am I an expert in mUI, so pardon me if my code is not according to those libs' best practices. The way I see it, I think you just need to add a handler to the autocomplete's `<TextField>` when there is a value change (whether it's from autofills or it's from user input).

Before showing my approach, I actually don't know how you manage the states for the inputs, so I will just add the states according to what I think are needed. So my approach is actually just to bind the value of the autocomplete to a state with `value={value}`, then in the `<TextField>`, I add `onChange` listener which listens to input change (normally it's only triggered by user change, but at least in my browser, it's **triggered by autofill change** as well). Inside the listener, it will try to check if the inputted string exists in the abbreviation mapping `stateNamesAndAbbreviations`, if it does exist, it **immediately** update the state `value` to the the abbreviation of the inputted string, if it doesn't exist, it will not do anything.

Here's the modified [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-glade-jucs58?file=/src/App.js), and here's the modified dropdown component:

```
const StateDropdown = ({ state, fieldUpdated }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const closeDropdown = () => setOpen(false);
  const openDropdown = () => setOpen(true);

  const dropdownInput = React.useRef(null);

  return (
    <Stack width={"100%"}>
      <InputLabel shrink>State</InputLabel>
      <Autocomplete
        open={open}
        onOpen={openDropdown}
        onClose={closeDropdown}
        value={value}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue || null);
        }}
        size="small"
        autoSelect
        autoHighlight
        selectOnFocus
        options={stateNamesAndAbbreviations.map((x) => x.abbreviation)}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            inputRef={dropdownInput}
            onChange={(event) => {
              const newValue = event.target.value;
              const existingState = stateNamesAndAbbreviations.find(
                (state) => state.name === newValue
              );

              // only force close dropdown when input is updated but is not on focus
              if (document.activeElement !== dropdownInput.current) {
                if (!!existingState) {
                  setValue(existingState.abbreviation);
                }

                closeDropdown();
              }
            }}
            variant="outlined"
            {...params}
            inputProps={{
              ...params.inputProps,
              autoComplete: "address-level1"
            }}
          />
        )}
      />
    </Stack>
  );
};
```

<strike>There is a potential problem that I could think of though. Suppose we have the following mapping:</strike>

```
[
    { name: "Indiana", abbreviation: "IN" },
    { name: "Indianajones", abbreviation: "IJ" },
]
```

When, for instance, a user is trying to input `Indianajones`, the dropdown will **immediately** change the input and select `IN` instead of allowing the user to continue typing. Despite that, it seems that this wouldn't happen here, since your mapping doesn't have any name which is a prefix of another name, so as long as the mapping is the one you provided, this won't happen.

I solved the potential problem by **only** update the dropdown value when the dropdown input is not being focused, so whenever the dropdown value is updated by anything than user input, it will be validated.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple you just need to see when autocomplete input of `AutoComplete`

```
const StateDropdown: React.FC<StateDropDownProps> = ({state, fieldUpdated}) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

  return (
    <Stack width={"100%"}>
        <InputLabel shrink>State</InputLabel>
        <Autocomplete size="small" 
            autoSelect
            autoHighlight
            selectOnFocus
            open={open}
            onOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
            onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
            value={value}
            onChange={(event, value) => setValue(value)}
            onInputChange={(event, value) => {
              if (!stateNamesAndAbbreviations.find(item => item.abbreviation === value)) return
              setValue(value)
              setOpen(true)
              setTimeout(() => setOpen(false)) // because on task end
            }}
            options={stateNamesAndAbbreviations.map((x) => x.abbreviation)}      
            data-testid={NewPaymentMethodTestHandles.State}
            onChange={(event, newValue) => fieldUpdated(PaymentMethodFields.state, newValue!)}
            renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField variant="outlined"
                    {...params}
                    error={state.isDirty && !state.isValid}
                    helperText={state.isDirty && !state.isValid ? "State is required" : null}
                    data-testid={NewPaymentMethodTestHandles.StateInput}
                    onChange={(event) => fieldUpdated(PaymentMethodFields.state, event.currentTarget.value)}
                    onBlur={() => !state.isDirty && fieldUpdated(PaymentMethodFields.state, state.value)}
                    inputProps={{
                        ...params.inputProps,
                        autoComplete: "address-level1",
                    }}
                />
            )}
        />
    </Stack>
  )
}
```

here is the example i solved your sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-kapitsa-ok15r6

Comment: At least on my machine, the problem still persists. When I used the most up to date version of Chrome and autofill an address "Arnold" in "OH" (I have saved the abbreviated form of his state's name in the browser) it still opens the dropdown and doesn't autofill his state.

Comment: @Shades i said in my comment i replaced your `.abbreviations` with `.name` because in japan no abbreviations are used. change `.name` to `.abbreviations` so it works for you

Comment: @Shades Do you understand what I just said?

Comment: Yes I understand what you just said, I'm unclear on why you edited the source code to work for Japan when it was stated in the question we're only serving US clients. Upon editing it would seem your code works, I will do additional testing to see if it's a serviceable solution.

Comment: you know i need to test it to make sure it works

Comment: You could have simply saved a US address to your browser and tested using that

Comment: the code I mentioned above is not modified to work in Japan

Comment: Fixing a few pieces of code will save more time than adding addresses I don't understand